# Estou com dúvida sobre atualizar um Jframe, Help plz

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um Quiz. Então gostaria de atualizar a mesma "tela" ou frame - como queiram - ou seja, tem a primeira pergunta, o usuario responde e o frame atualiza com nova pergunta e assim por diante. Minha ideia era de fazer tudo na mesma tela, porém aceito sugestões, caso recomendem eu criar outros frames(o que seria o mais fácil, porem mais trabalhoso).
Segue o código:
String[] perguntas = new String[3];
        perguntas[0] = "Pergunta 1 ?";
        perguntas[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lcVo.png) = "Pergunta 2 ?";
        perguntas[2] = "Pergunta 3 ?";

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 600, 471);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 167, 616, 265);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    contentPane.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    rdA = new JRadioButton(" A");
    rdA.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    rdA.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    rdA.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    rdA.setBounds(24, 53, 48, 23);
    panel.add(rdA);

    rdB = new JRadioButton(" B");
    rdB.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    rdB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    rdB.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    rdB.setBounds(24, 94, 48, 23);
    panel.add(rdB);

    rdC = new JRadioButton(" C");
    rdC.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    rdC.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    rdC.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    rdC.setBounds(24, 140, 48, 23);
    panel.add(rdC);

    rdD = new JRadioButton(" D");
    rdD.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    rdD.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    rdD.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    rdD.setBounds(24, 186, 48, 23);
    panel.add(rdD);

    alternativas = new ButtonGroup ();
    alternativas.add(rdA);
    alternativas.add(rdB);
    alternativas.add(rdC);
    alternativas.add(rdD);


    JButton btnAvan = new JButton("Avan\u00E7ar");
    btnAvan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        }
    });
    btnAvan.setBounds(292, 231, 89, 23);
    panel.add(btnAvan);
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Acredito eu, que a maneira mais eficaz que tenha (até onde saiba) para fazer isso, é criar um objeto, *Panel* ou *Canvas*, com tudo organizado, ou chamar uma função que reorganiza da maneira que quiser, assim, basta fazer uma simples manipulação de variáveis, colocando alguns parâmetros no método construtor do objeto (ou função), pois assim torna-se mais fácil instanciar esse objeto da maneira que quiser.

Um **EXEMPLO** de como seria instanciado:

```
PainelPergunta novaPergunta = new PainelPergunta(pergunta, alternativa1, alternativa2, alternativa3, alternativa4, resposta);
```

Basta organizar seu objeto com alguns algoritmos simples, então no exemplo acima, você pode criar um novo objeto, passando os parâmetros necessários.

Ou também, pode manter sempre o mesmo objeto, e reorganizar os itens e opções contidas nele através de uma função:

```
NovaPergunta(pergunta, alternativa1, alternativa2, alternativa3, alternativa4, resposta);
```